# serialization/deserialization of Node JS "undefined" in other languages

Tags: javascript, node.js, msgpack

I'm serializing some data using **message pack**[(@msgpack/msgpack)](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@msgpack/msgpack) on a Node JS server and passing the serialized data via an HTTP communication to another software that is written in C++.
My question is, what would a deserialized js "undefined" object look like on the C++ side?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please add some info; are you using JSON? Is it this library: https://github.com/msgpack/msgpack-node?

Comment: @ChrisG no it's not JSON. It's binary serialization of JS objects using msgpack (I've also added the link). The library you linked in your comment is also an implementation of message pack for node js which in its doc it says **"undefined" is type-mapped to msgpack-nil** so I know the answer... thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@msgpack/msgpack#messagepack-mapping-table) says `undefined` and `null` are mapped to msgpack's [`nil, which is specified`](https://github.com/msgpack/msgpack/blob/master/spec.md#nil-format)  to be a single `0xC0` byte (192 in decimal).

To wit:

```
> require("@msgpack/msgpack").encode(undefined)
Uint8Array(1) [ 192 ]
```